# Droid Turbo on Linux Mint 17

Tags: android

I'm having trouble connecting the (Android) Droid Turbo to my Linux Mint 17 laptop.

I've already tried several fixes, including installing mtpfs and the gMTP application, but I have had no luck. It seems that the laptop is not recognizing the phone: if I type

```
mtp-detect
```

I get the following:

```
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6

 Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.
```

My phone says that I am connected as a media device. I have an option to "show software installation popup on your computer" but this software is strictly Windows. I currently have it unchecked, but checking it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Use the AirDroid app.

Investigation:

I'm also using Droid Turbo with Linux Mint 17, and I had the same issue.
One thing worth trying is sudo mtp-detect:

> $ sudo mtp-detect
>   Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: >1.1.6
>
> Listing raw device(s)
>   Device 0 (VID=22b8 and PID=2ea8) is UNKNOWN.
>   Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
>     Found 1 device(s):
>     22b8:2ea8 @ bus 3, dev 11
>   Attempting to connect device(s)
>   Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
>   USB low-level info:
>   ...

Then if you do sudo mtp-connect, you'll see this:

> Usage: connect  
>   Commands: --delete [filename]
>            --sendfile [source] [destination]
>            --sendtrack [source] [destination]
>            --getfile [source] [destination]
>            --newfolder [foldername]

I found that using sending a file to the root path / works, and it shows up in the SD Card folder on AirDroid. Trying /SD\ Card or /sdcard didn't work.

Here's a working example of sending a ringtone file to the correct folder:

> sudo mtp-connect --sendfile Moonlight\ Sonata\ Ringtone.mp3 /Ringtones

It's a bit slow, but it works. (Note: Don't put a / after the destination folder)

Here are some useful folders:
/DCIM/Camera
/Notifications
/Music

But seeing as the AirDroid application works well for all of this and makes seeing the file structure easy, that seems like the best solution.

Disadvantage of AirDroid:
The file has to pass through the Internet, so it could be slow.